# Connecting datapower and worklight client side

Tags: ajax, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-datapower

Im trying to connect a worklight app with a datapower using $.ajax() from the client side using this code on the main js:

```
function authDP(username, password) {

$.ajax("http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador", {
    success : function() {
        var invocationData = {
            adapter : "B2CAdapter",
            procedure : "setUserIdentity",
            parameters : [ username, password ]
        };
        myChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});
        alert("Login correcto");
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Failed: " + status + " ; " + error);
    },
    headers : {

        "Authorization" : "Basic "
                + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password)


    }
});
```

}

but the chrome console returns this (on chrome):

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador 401 (Unauthorized) wljq.js:8542
OPTIONS http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador Origin http://pc-ayi-0204:10080 is not      allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. wljq.js:8542
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador. Origin http://pc-ayi-0204:10080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

and this on firefox:

```
[11:55:22.272] OPTIONS http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 38ms]
```

Is there something that im missing on the headers? Because in the firefox console/request/headers/ section i only see this:

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Origin:http://pc-ayi-0204:10080
Host:192.168.44.201:2051
Connection:keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

and i dont see the Basic user:pass values, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make arbitrary requests outside of your domain from the client side using AJAX.  See for example:

[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to look into following piece of error

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador 401 (Unauthorized) wljq.js:8542 OPTIONS http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador **Origin http://pc-ayi-0204:10080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.** wljq.js:8542 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.44.201:2051/cotizador. Origin http://pc-ayi-0204:10080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am not sure what construct you are calling on datapower [MPGW or Web service proxy] but whatever it is, it seems to have ACL applied on its Front Side Handler. That ACL defines IP addresses which are allowed to call the construct. I am not sure what is the exact use case in your scenario but to correct the problem you need to remove the ACL from the Datapower Front Side Handler object.

- Ajitabh